# How to fix a responsive image that works on Firefox but not on Chrome and Safari?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a `row` with a bunch of `img` whose size are capped by their height, and these are displayed properly on Firefox, but stretch on Chrome and Safari.

Firefox
[image: Firefox]

Chrome
[image: Chrome]

Safari
[image: Safari]

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center" style="padding-top: 15px">
  <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Tools & Software</h6>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <img src="img/icons/adobe.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Adobe Creative Suite" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Adobe Creative Suite">
    <img src="img/icons/gravit.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Gravit Designer" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Gravit Designer">
    <img src="img/icons/macos.png" class="skill-icon" alt="macOS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="macOS">
    <img src="img/icons/windows.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Windows" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Windows">                
    <img src="img/icons/adobe.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Adobe Creative Suite" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Adobe Creative Suite">
    <img src="img/icons/gravit.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Gravit Designer" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Gravit Designer">
    <img src="img/icons/macos.png" class="skill-icon" alt="macOS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="macOS">
    <img src="img/icons/windows.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Windows" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Windows">                
    <img src="img/icons/adobe.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Adobe Creative Suite" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Adobe Creative Suite">
    <img src="img/icons/gravit.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Gravit Designer" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Gravit Designer">
    <img src="img/icons/macos.png" class="skill-icon" alt="macOS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="macOS">
    <img src="img/icons/windows.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Windows" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Windows">                
    <img src="img/icons/adobe.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Adobe Creative Suite" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Adobe Creative Suite">
    <img src="img/icons/gravit.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Gravit Designer" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Gravit Designer">
    <img src="img/icons/macos.png" class="skill-icon" alt="macOS" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="macOS">
    <img src="img/icons/windows.png" class="skill-icon" alt="Windows" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Windows">              
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.skill-icon {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

How can I have the dimensions and responsiveness I'm having on Firefox on the other browsers? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem exists when we have:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I cannot tell which browser renders the images correctly, but you can equalize them either by setting to default:

```
.skill-icon {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

or by removing paddings.

First solution [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4epfn5rk/).

More about [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: The `box-sizing: content-box;` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the flexbox of the parent row is messing up your styling.
Just change the style of the row to something else that suits your needs, like display: block; or display: inline;

This should fix the issue.